# Maps $\phi:C^{\infty}(Y) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(X)$ as pullbacks

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've just begun reading through Joyce's [D-manifolds and d-orbifolds: a theory of derived differential geometry](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/joyce/dmbook.pdf), and I've come across a seemingly innocuous statement that isn't quite clear to me.  Specifically, in $\S$1.2 he gives the following definition (in my words):

> A **$\mathbf{C^{\infty}}$-ring** is a pair $(\mathfrak{C},\{\Phi_n\}_{n\geq 0})$ where $\mathfrak{C}$ is a set and $\Phi_n:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \text{Maps}(\mathfrak{C}^n,\mathfrak{C})$ satisfies (I will drop the subscript $n$, as no confusion should arise):
>
> (i)  For any $m,n\geq 0$, $\ f_1,\cdots,f_m\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^m)$, we can define $h\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by
>
> $$ h(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=g(f_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n),\cdots,f_m(x_1,\cdots,x_n)). $$
>
> Then for any $c_1,\cdots,c_n\in\mathfrak{C}$, $\Phi$ must satisfy
>
> $$ \Phi_h(c_1,\cdots,c_n)=\Phi_g(\Phi_{f_1}(c_1,\cdots,c_n),\cdots,\Phi_{f_m}(c_1,\cdots,c_n)). $$
>
> (ii)  For all $1\leq j\leq n$, the canonical projection maps $\pi_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ must satisfy
>
> $$ \Phi_{\pi_j}(c_1,\cdots,c_n)=c_j $$
>
> for all $c_1,\cdots,c_n\in\mathfrak{C}$.

Then there is a straightforward notion of a morphism between these structures:

> A **morphism** between $C^{\infty}$-rings $(\mathfrak{C},\Phi)$ and $(\mathfrak{D},\Psi)$ is a map $\phi:\mathfrak{C}\rightarrow\mathfrak{D}$ such that
>
> $$ \begin{array}{ccc} \mathfrak{C}^n & \xrightarrow{\Phi_f} & \mathfrak{C} \\ \downarrow^{\phi^n} & & \downarrow^{\phi} \\ \mathfrak{D}^n & \xrightarrow{\Psi_f} & \mathfrak{D} \end{array}$$
>
> commutes for all $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $n\geq 0$.

The basic example, as hinted at by the name of these objects, is $C^{\infty}(X)$ where $X$ is a smooth manifold.  By defining

$$ [\Phi_f(c_1,\cdots,c_n)](x)=f(c_1(x),\cdots,c_n(x)) $$

for $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $c_1,\cdots,c_n\in C^{\infty}(X)$, and $n\geq 0$, one clearly gets the structure of a $C^{\infty}$-ring.  Moreover, for a smooth map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, the pullback $f^{\ast}:C^{\infty}(Y)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(X)$ is clearly a morphism of $C^{\infty}$-rings.  But then Joyce goes on to say,

*Furthermore (at least for $Y$ without boundary), every $C^{\infty}$-ring morphism $\phi:C^{\infty}(Y)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(X)$ is of the form $\phi=f^{\ast}$ for a unique smooth map $f:X\rightarrow Y$.*

> **My question(s):  Why is this true?  How is the map $f$ constructed?  What about the construction fails if $Y$ has boundary?  Is this statement true regardless of whether or not $\phi$ is a $C^{\infty}$-ring morphism?**

The thing that came immediately to mind was defining $f:X\rightarrow Y$ by

$$ f(x) = g^{-1}(\phi(g)(x)), $$

so that $f^{\ast}(g)=g(g^{-1}(\phi(g)))=\phi(g)$, but of course this only works if $g$ is surjective, and the equation $\phi=f^{\ast}$ only holds for this specific $g$.  I cannot, however, think of any other way of finding $f$… any suggestions?  References?

Comment: I'm expecting that it is not true for arbitrary maps $\phi:C^{\infty}(Y)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(X)$, but it does actually need to be a $C^{\infty}$-ring morphism… and that the proof just involves a clever choice of $f$ and $n$ so that the commutativity of the diagram gives me what I want… but I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: Not an answer, but this reminds me of the Banach Stone theorem.  The construction of $f_\phi$ may not be so trivial.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Yeah, I just realized that this sounds very familiar to the Gelfand-Naimark theorem as well (at least a smooth manifold version of it).  Perhaps those types of results are what I need… thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having finally had a little more time to return to this question, I searched around a bit more and found that this result is given by the following Proposition from Joyce's [Algebraic Geometry over $C^{\infty}$-rings](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0023):

> **Proposition 3.3.**  Let $X,Y$ be manifolds with corners.  Then the map $f\mapsto f^{\ast}$ from weakly smooth maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to morphisms of $C^{\infty}$-rings $\phi:C^{\infty}(Y)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(X)$ is a 1-1 correspondence.

Here, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is *weakly smooth* if it is continuous, and for any charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, then the map

$$ \psi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi:(f\circ\phi)^{-1}(\psi(V))\rightarrow V $$

is smooth as a map between euclidean spaces.  Then one can define a notion of *smoothness* for maps between manifolds with corners as follows (from Joyce's [On manifolds with corners](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518), $\S$3):

> Suppose $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y\in Y$ , and $\beta$ is a local boundary component of $Y$ at $y$.  Let $(V,b)$ be a boundary defining function for $Y$ at $(y,\beta)$.  Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, and $b\circ f : f^{−1}(V)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a weakly smooth map.  We require that either $b\circ f\equiv 0$ on an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $f^{−1}(V)$, or $(f^{−1}(V),b\circ f)$ is a boundary defining function for $X$ at $(x,\tilde{\beta})$, for some unique local boundary component $\tilde{\beta}$ of $X$ at $x$.

At any rate, in the case of manifolds without boundary, smoothness trivially implies weak smoothness.  The proof of Prop. 3.3 apparently follows from Prop. I.1.5 of Moerdijk and Reyes' [Models for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4143-8).  Once I have a chance to get to the library to pick up a copy, I'll try to edit this answer to give a proof for anyone interested.  Until then, it seems that the (tentative) answers to my questions are:

> **Why is this true?  How is the map f constructed?**  See Prop. I.1.5 in the above reference, until I have time to get a copy and digest it.
>
> **What about the construction fails if Y has boundary?**  Apparently nothing -- an analogous result (with smoothness replaced by weak smoothness) seems to hold for manifolds with boundary and manifolds with corners.
>
> **Is this statement true regardless of whether or not $\phi$ is a $C^{\infty}$-ring morphism?**  Apparently $\phi$ does need to be a $C^{\infty}$-ring morphism.